# Executing Erlang shell command from Javascript (Electron) is not returning any output

Tags: javascript, erlang, electron

I am trying to call an Erlang module function from javascript but the webpage does not display anything in the 'erl_ver' div element in the index.html file.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to App</h1>
<div id='erl_ver'></div> <div id='electron_ver'></script>.
<script type="text/javascript">
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/')) + "/";
var e = require('child_process');
e.exec('erl -noshell -s shell_info get_ver -s erlang halt',{cwd: dir}, function(err,stdout, stderr) {
    document.getElementById('erl_ver').innerHTML = "Erlang shell version: " + stdout;
    document.getElementById('electron_ver').innerHTML = ", Electron version: " + process.versions['electron'];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### shell_info.erl

```
-module(shell_info).
-compile(export_all).

get_ver() ->
    io:format(erlang:system_info(system_version)).
```

However, if I remove the cwd option from the javascript exec function, in the index.html file, I get the following error on the webpage:

```
Erlang shell version: {"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{shell_info,get_ver,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1054}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1034}]}]}}
, Electron version: 0.33.6
```

How do I display the expected shell_info:get_ver() output on the webpage?

Expected output:

```
C:\Users\eausaig\Downloads\electron-v0.33.6-win32-x64\erlang_studio>erl -noshell
 -s shell_info get_ver -s erlang halt
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]

C:\Users\eausaig\Downloads\electron-v0.33.6-win32-x64\erlang_studio>
```

I modified the code by running the exec function in the main process and then calling the exec function from the render process (webpage) using an ipc communication. I still got the same error message mentioned above. Using the -pa option does not display the output from the shell_info:get_ver() command:

```
ipc.on('erlang_version', function(event, arg) {
  var e = require('child_process');
  e.exec('erl -pa ' + __dirname + '-s shell_info get_ver -s erlang halt', function(err,stdout, stderr) {
  event.sender.send('erlang_version_response', stdout);
  });
});
```

Output with the -pa option added:

```
Erlang shell version:
, Electron version: 0.33.6
```

Note that it works for Windows cmd commands e.g ver.
I replaced 'erl -pa ' + __dirname + '-s shell_info get_ver -s erlang halt' with 'ver' and it displays an output.

```
Erlang shell version: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
, Electron version: 0.33.6
```

Issue has been fixed. It was syntax error. I omitted the space between __dirname and '-s'. The correct syntax should be:

```
e.exec('erl -pa ' + __dirname + ' -s shell_info get_ver -s erlang halt', function(err,stdout, stderr)
```

Result after correcting the syntax error in the command:

```
Erlang shell version: Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10]
, Electron version: 0.33.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erlang will look for the shell_info module (and any other module) according to the code path. If you have a beam file in your current directory it will find it, but your web server won't find it there.

You can set extra code paths by using the -pa parameter to erl, or setting the ERL_LIBS environment variable, or you can install your module in the existing default code path.

On my system the default code path is "/usr/lib/erlang/lib":

```
$ erl
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0]     [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> code:lib_dir().
"/usr/lib/erlang/lib"
2>
```

Note that if you add PATH it will look for your shell_info.beam in PATH/X/ebin (where X is anything (should be appname-version)).

Comment: I already tried the -pa option. It wasn't displaying any output. The webpage (index.html) and the shell_info.beam file are in the same folder. I am running this app on Windows 7.

Comment: Issue fixed. The issue was a syntax error. I omitted the space between the directory name (__dirname) and the '-s' option in  e.exec('erl -pa ' + __dirname + ' -s shell_info get_ver -s erlang halt', function(err,stdout, stderr)

Comment: Well done. The HTML and shell_info.beam in the same dir does not help, it's the CWD of the web server that matters in this case, which isn't likely to be the directory containing that HTML file. Not sure about Windows, but on Linux 'erl' is a shell script which sets some variables and runs 'erlexec'. If Windows is similar you could run your own front script (instead of erl) which sets ERL_LIBS, and use that for your app, or set ERL_LIBS for your whole web server process. If you don't want to install your module in the standard place that is. That'll save you copying that path everywhere.